# How to check sharepoint list date column is empty?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, linq

How to check sharepoint list date column is empty?
I want to check in back end code.

```
 IEnumerable<DataRow> x = from laptop in dtList.AsEnumerable()
                                     join lapLegend in dtCollection.AsEnumerable() on list1.Field<string>("Name") equals list2.Field<string>("LaptopName")
                                     where list2.Field<DateTime>("ReturnedDate") !=
                                     select laptop;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check for `!= null`

Example found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798474.aspx

Comment: but if a field is empty, it's null, right?

Comment: != null works fine if column has data, but if date column is empty exception thrown as  Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type.

Comment: have you tried (DateTime?) null ?

Comment: Yes. Same error pops up